# Unable to find the Kendo Grid Pager using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update the kendo controls to a newer version(2020.3.915.440) in my existing project. Before we used kendo controls 2014.3.1119.440 version.

After updating to a newer version I am unable to get the pager dropdown using below code. It is giving an error message '**Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined**'. It was working with the existing version. Can you help me with this?

```
   //add change event to kendo pager pageSizes dropdown
        var grid = $("#RptGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var pageSizeDropDownList = grid.wrapper.children(".k-grid-pager").find("select").data("kendoDropDownList");

        pageSizeDropDownList.bind("change", function(e) {
            var pageSize = e.sender.value();
            localStorage.setItem('RptItemsPerPage', pageSize);
        });
```

Comment: The error means that `pageSizeDropDownList` is undefined. It suggests that `grid` is found, yet something else is not. Try adding `console.log(grid);` Maybe there are too many children or something else is too ambigious. It's not clear which jQuery version is now being used. Aside, you might consider moving from `.bind()` to `.on()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this using [this Kendo example page](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) and the following code worked for me (I updated the code below to match your grid ID however)):

```
var grid = $("#RptGrid").data("kendoGrid");

var pageSizeDropDownList = grid.wrapper.children(".k-grid-pager").find(".k-dropdown select").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var pageSizeDropDownList = $("#RptGrid .k-grid-pager [data-role=dropdownlist]").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

There is now more than one 'select' element within the .k-grid-pager element which is why your original selector no longer works.

G_Ps answer is just as good, we've both simply used a more specific selector. In cases like this, use the browser dev tools to inspect the element to see how to select what you need.